# Overload only if the type has a "<<" operator?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, type-traits

I have a function that is overloaded for many types.
But my current problem is due to that (LWS here : [lws](http://liveworkspace.org/code/70af7df0a40e16612591381c56535b0d)) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <type_traits>

// First version
template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type> 
std::string f(const T& x)
{
    return std::to_string(x);
}

// Second version
template<typename... T> 
std::string f(const std::tuple<T...>& x)
{
    return std::to_string(sizeof...(T)); // It's just an example here
}

// Third version
template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type, class = void> 
std::string f(const T& x)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss<<x;
    return oss.str();
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::cout<<f(42)<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<f(std::string("Hello World"))<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<f(std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int>(4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42))<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

My problem is that when we call `f()` for a `std::tuple`, the third version is executed and not the second one.

How to solve this problem (a solution would be to allow the third version only for types where `<<` is defined, but I don't know how to do that, and if this is the best way to solve the problem) ?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the new C++11 stuff, but I guess you need to extend the static check `std::is_fundamental<T>` with checking if a  `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const & T)` is available.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error (short: SFINAE)

Comment: @g-makulik: checking if that exists is much harder than you'd think.

Comment: @MooingDuck Just for curiosity do you have a pointer how to do it? I've been using static checks for concept validation so far (generating compilation error), not for specialization selection, but shouldn't that work similarly?

Comment: @g-makulik: generating a compilation error is _easy_.  Specialization selection is not similar at all, and quite complicated.  See the SFINAE link that tstenner posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your only problem is that you forgot to `#include <tuple>`, which is shown in the error on LWS. [Here's a fixed version](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6df329fc40e39c4a7466694851978ecd) that compiles correctly. The second overload is always a better match than the third one since it's *more specialized* according to partial ordering rules.

If you still want to know how to check for a functions existence that triggers SFINAE if it's not there, check [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154394/500104) on a question dedicated to that topic. :) It even has an example that pretty much matches what you want.